# How to return less information from aws ec2 describe-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

When running `aws ec2 describe-instances` a LOT of information is returned per instance. Is there a way to easily review a table of instances and their states? (i.e. without much of the other information)

Note: some other IAAS/PAAS tools typically display less information unless you explicitly ask for more with `--verbose` or similar. Whereas aws seems to give a lot by default

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a few fields likely to be of interest, namely:

- Availability Zone
- State Name (e.g. running, stopped etc)
- Launch Time
- Instance Type (e.g. t2.medium)
- Instance ID

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, LaunchTime, InstanceType,  InstanceId]' --output text
```

The above can easily be edited to include (or remove fields) as necessary

This comes from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter) thanks @Dusan Bajic